# Creating a distance buffer between two sprites

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I have two sprites, one "tracks" and follows the other. I already have that working, so a fish will follow a bubble around the screen (it will rotate towards the direction as well as move toward it). Here's a diagram on how it works and what I want to happen:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to "buffer" my fish the correct (x,y) away from the bubble center, but I'm not sure how. Here's my code, it runs on a schedule (60*second):

```
- (void) nextFrame:(ccTime)dt {

    float dx = bubble.position.x - fish.position.x;
    float dy = bubble.position.y - fish.position.y;
    float d = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    float v = 200;

    if (d >  1){
        fish.position = ccp( fish.position.x + dx/d * v *dt, 
                               fish.position.y + dy/d * v *dt);
    } else {
        fish.position = ccp(bubble.position.x, bubble.position.y);
    }

    float angle = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(atan2f(dx, dy));
    angle -= 90;

    fish.rotation = angle;
    if(bubble.position.x < fish.position.x){
        fish.flipY = YES;
    } else {
        fish.flipY = NO;
    }
}
```

Any ideas or help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hey, can I ask you what you use to make your diagrams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the seeds of a solution already in your division-by-zero check. You want the fish to stop moving at a longer distance, so change the condition on `d`. Replace your first if/else with:

```
if (d > radiusOfBubblePlusRadiusOfFish){
    fish.position = ccp( fish.position.x + dx/d * v *dt, 
                           fish.position.y + dy/d * v *dt);
}
```

and keep everything else the same.

Answer (score 0):

Don't calculate the fish position as the centre of the fish, rather the position in front of the mouth.

So move until fish.position + offset = bubble.position.